# Do I need to set the primary-foreign key relationship to do the join?

Tags: mysql, database

I've got a database with five tables and the structures are as follows:

```
DROP DATABASE IF EXISTS newsagent;

CREATE DATABASE newsagent;
USE newsagent;

CREATE TABLE paper (id VARCHAR(20)PRIMARY KEY,name VARCHAR(30)) ENGINE = INNODB;

CREATE TABLE round (id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY,name VARCHAR(20),paperboy VARCHAR(20)) ENGINE = INNODB;

CREATE TABLE subscriber (id VARCHAR(10) PRIMARY KEY,name VARCHAR(20),address VARCHAR(30),suburb VARCHAR(20),state VARCHAR(3),postcode VARCHAR(4),round_id INTEGER NOT NULL,FOREIGN KEY (round_id) REFERENCES round (id) ON UPDATE CASCADE ON DELETE RESTRICT) ENGINE = INNODB;

CREATE TABLE current_order (paper_id VARCHAR(20),subscriber_id VARCHAR(10),PRIMARY KEY (paper_id, subscriber_id),FOREIGN KEY (paper_id) REFERENCES paper (id) ON UPDATE CASCADE ON DELETE RESTRICT,FOREIGN KEY (subscriber_id) REFERENCES subscriber (id) ON UPDATE CASCADE ON DELETE RESTRICT) ENGINE = INNODB;

CREATE TABLE receipt (id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTO_INCREMENT, receipt_date DATE,paid_till_date DATE,paper_id VARCHAR(20),subscriber_id VARCHAR(10)) ENGINE = INNODB;
```

I am supposed to run some queries to retrieve current orders that have overdue subscription payment. The query is below:

```
SELECT DISTINCT t1.* FROM current_order AS t1 LEFT
JOIN receipt AS t2 USING (paper_id, subscriber_id)
WHERE t2.paid_till_date IS NULL
OR t2.paid_till_date < Now() 
ORDER BY subscriber_id, paper_id;
```

This query runs ok, But I've noticed that there is no primary/child relationship between the current_order table and the receipt table.

- Do I need to set out the relationship? How to make the relationship?
- Do I reference the `Paper_ID` and `Subscription_ID` to the compound primary key in current_order or is it better to reference them separately to paper table and subscription table?
- Will it have any impact on the query accuracy and the database performance?

Answer (score 1):

You asked

> Do I need to set out the relationship?

You don't need to establish FK relationships for your queries to work correctly. FK relationships help you maintain database integrity, by causing INSERT and UPDATE operations to fail if they break the key relationships. Without that integrity, you may have some orphan rows in some tables -- rows unrelated to rows in other tables. This can drive your auditors, and you, crazy because they represent misplaced orders and transactions.

> How to make the relationship?

You already have, by making the id columns have the same data type in all your tables, and by using them in your JOIN operations. You have also rigged up some FK relationships.

> Do I reference the Paper_ID and Subscription_ID to the compound primary key in current_order or is it better to reference them separately to paper table and subscription table?

Reference them separately, because that represents the relationships more accurately.

> Will it have any impact on the query accuracy and the database performance?

Good FK setups *may* help query performance because the indexes which implement them may be useful to the query planner.

The constraints will make your data more consistent. That may help with query accuracy.

Pro tip: avoid `JOIN ...  USING(col1,col2)` because it can be ambiguous in more complex queries.  Instead do this sort of thing.

```
 FROM tablea a
 JOIN tableb b ON a.col1 = b.col1 AND a.col2 = b.col2
```

It's a little more verbose and a lot more specific.

Comment: Thanks for your input, I am thinking to index the pay-till-date in the receipt table because it is searched in the query. I guess it will make my query run more faster?  Or is there any other field needed to be indexed to a quicker search?

Comment: The `DISTINCT` isn't helpful in your query; all your id values are different anyhow. A compound index on `(paid_till_date , paper_id, subscriber_id )` will help this query the most. A simple index on `paid_till_date` will help a lot, but not as much as the compound one.   More optimization requires looking at the EXPLAIN output.

Comment: THE DISTINCT IS ACTUALY HELPFULL BECAUSE Without it the result is with repetitive fileds. However, I still dont undersand why I need to do a join here. Why can't we just select from the receipt table? and why do we need to set the condition where paid_till_date is null? what is it for since there is actually not nul data in that field.